# Cannot get mustache file to read sendmail.php file

Tags: ruby, phpmailer, mustache

I have a project downloaded from github it uses mustache files and ruby.The project required account setup to send an email straight from the page in which a secret token is generated however i do not want the account part of the project therefore the email setup does not load up when i start my modified version of the project.

It seems to be difficult to get the mustache file in which my homepage is to read any other file for example i set up phpmailer and have it working however when i try to get it to work with the project 'not found' just appears on the top left corner.

Can I perhaps convert the mustache file to html which might make it a bit easier or how can i deal with these mustache files.

Comment: Please show us some code and mustache configuration files so we can help you.

Comment: You're using ruby and PHPMailer? I'm not surprised you're having trouble...

Comment: Im not sure what to actually post beacuse its more of a lack of knowledge on mustache thats my problem.I have the project compiling and have it looking the way I want but a functioning email from the homepage.mustache file is the issue.But if you do get a moment you could have a look at the original proj its onetimesecret

Comment: well they are not actually working together the project is coded in Ruby and I am trying to get an email working just to take the genereated token as an attachment.Should I be going in another direction?

Comment: Come on Synchro gimme something positive

Comment: I'm with Synchro here. PHPMailer has no business being involved in a Ruby project. The "When in Rome..." principle applies here. Use a Ruby mailer like the venerable [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) package, or use a PHP-only solution without any Ruby involved.

Comment: ok thanks i have tried using mail, sendgrid actionmailer but trying to get from the mustache file to anything outside it is proving really difficult.it just says not found.This may be becuase theres already a post made to an external entity for the generated passwod